# Will asp.net mvc  web site created using HTML5 work "out of the box" on mobile devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, mobile

i am building a new web site using asp.net mvc3 web application ,, and i found some free HTML5 templates in the web which i can add to my _layout view in my mvc3 web application. i read that HTML5 is able to automatically adapt to the screen size of any devices .

So does this mean that incase i use HTML5 inside my layout view , then my web site can be accessed using different mobile devices and the layout of my web site will automatically adapt to the screen size of the mobile devices?
BR

Comment: You said : `i read that HTML5 is able to automatically adapt to the screen size of any devices`. It's not actually true. Html5 (and I think that CSS 3 is the true angel) provides tools for making "adjustable" layout. In all cases you have to design your site accordingly. Look at [So] for example, if you reduce the with of your window, the right menu will eventually disappear if your browser is HTML5 compliant. It's also true for mobile. Anyways, the screen and input device are very different from a desktop computer, a mobile phone, etc. You should have a dedicated mobile version of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so simple. You need to contend with

- Big variety of mobile devices. Some support HTML5, some partially support it and some don't support it at all.
- Even if a mobile device does support HTML5, a mobile screen is a lot smaller than a desktop so it may not be able to rearrange the view properly.
- How a user interacts with a mobile web app is quite different to a desktop web app, so even if it did rearrange the view properly the user experience could be crap.
- A mobile user may be connecting over a low bandwidth connection. What size are your web pages, and are they suitable for distribution over 2g, 2.5g or 3g ?

Comment: thanks for your reply ,, but it was mentioned on the wikipedia that ""HTML5 is also a potential candidate for cross-platform mobile applications"",, so i think they meant that it can adapt to the mobile devices. Second question then what will be the advantagies of an HTML5 web site compared to HTML4 for example on mobile devices? is there any advantigies?

Comment: @johnG: I think “HTML5” here is being used in the broader marketing sense used (among others) by Apple, to refer to HTML5, CSS3, and anything else vaguely new that browsers support. It’s not referring to HTML5 as opposed to HTML4. I’m not sure where you read about “automatically” adapting to different screen sizes. HTML’s layout model has always done that to an extent; the CSS3 difference is media queries that allow you to manually set different styles based on the features (e.g. window width) of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, not always. HTML 5 is a very broad term and there are many devices. There is no real guarantee that something you write in any version of HTML 5 will show up as you want it in every browser except via testing it and experience from testing.

That said, I think you are referring to [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), which are not really related to ASP.NET MVC 3 or HTML 5. From the caniuse site [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), you can get an idea of which browsers support media queries.

If you use CSS 3 media queries properly, and the browsers which you are targeting support the feature, then the answer to your question will be yes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works automatically but I'd give it a guarded "maybe". The MVC3 sites I've developed work well on iPhone, iPad, Android and Windows Phone. For example [link](http://www.microlightgiftvoucher.com)

Still needs to be valid HTML5, so I'd suggest using a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) though.

Screen size adaptation isn't a particular feature of HTML5 per se, it's a feature of a competent fluid design with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

They should *work* out of the box on mobile devices (in the original iPhone demo, Steve Jobs showed how the iPhone did a good job of rendering existing websites), but there won’t be any *automatic* adaptation to screen size beyond what HTML already provides.

As far as HTML goes, `<meta name="viewport">` can go a long way towards helping your site’s layout on Mobile WebKit-based devices (which is all iPhones, and I believe all Android devices). See e.g.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
- http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html.